# Uninstalling nginx gives an error - No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx

Tags: nginx, homebrew

Recently I upgraded my OS to Monterey 12.3.1.

When I am trying to uninstall nginx using the command `brew uninstall nginx`, I get the following error:

`Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx`

Any reason for why this is happening?